# Do orthonormal matrices have a geometric interpretation or contextual importance?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

I understand how certain matrices can be orthonormal and the conditions necessary for that. I don't understand its geometric relevance. For instance in a vector space the axis would be orthonormal and perhaps another set of matrices, but so what ?

Comment: The geometric significance of orthonormal matrices is that they describe linear transformations that preserve angles between vectors and magnitudes of vectors. Also they're usually called orthogonal matrices.

Comment: What do you mean by “the axis would be othonormal” and “perhaps another set of matrices”?

Comment: I mean for instance that you can have matrices that don't have 1s or 0s.

Comment: If $Q$ is a real $n \times n$ matrix with orthonormal columns, then $Q^T$ is the change of basis matrix from the standard basis to the basis consisting of columns of $Q$.

Comment: Rotation matrices are orthogonal matrices whose elements are not 0s and 1s, in general.  Do you know how to right down the matrix of a plane rotation?

Comment: How do you write them? Only with the cosines and sines. From the book I get that: \begin{bmatrix}
  cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta) \\
sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) \\

\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $M$ is orthonormal and $u,v$ are vectors,the distance from $u$ to $v$ equals the distance from $Mu$ to $Mv$. So the function that maps each $u$ to $Mu$ does not change angles or  shapes.  Such a function can be interpreted geometrically as a rotation, keeping the origin fixed, or a rotation  followed by  a  reflection in a mirror (still keeping the origin fixed).

Comment: what do you mention under *distance of vectors*?